# Search an object from a list with its partial attribute value

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have a list object which I load from a web service. My list comes in this form:

```
list = [ {id:"name1 Surname1" , nb:120} ,
         {id:"name2", nb:632} , 
         {id:"name3Surname3", nb:102} , 
         {id:"surname4", nb:896} 
       ]
```

My searching strategy is to go by **"id"**.
As you can see I have different formats:

separated name-surname with space, only name, only surname.

My purpose is to search member by id (its name or surname values). 
My result should be items whose IDS are containing my searched value item.

**For example :**

- If I search for : "name1"  -> **result** : name1 Surname1
- If I search for : "name1 Surn" -> **result** : name1 Surname1
- If I search for : "name1 SurAAA" -> **result** : (nothing)
- If I search for : "AAAA Surname1" -> **result** : (nothing)
- If I search for : "name1Surname1" -> **result** : (nothing)
- If I search for : "name" -> **result** : name1 Surname1 , name2 , name3Surname3 , surname4

***To summarize :***

I should search items:

- corresponding for my searched item
- beginning with my searched item

I have tried the **filter** solution, like the following:

```
findItems(name) {
      this.splits = name.toLowerCase().split(' ');
      if (this.splits.length >= 1) {
        results = this.namesList.filter(item => this.splits.indexOf(item.brand.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
      }else {
        results = [];
      }
  }
```

But this solution is only searching for items corresponding **exactly** to my searched item, and it lacks the **partial search**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use filter and includes

```js
let list = [ {id:"name1 Surname1" , nb:120} ,
         {id:"name2", nb:632} , 
         {id:"name3Surname3", nb:102} , 
         {id:"surname4", nb:896} 
       ] 
      
searchForString = (list,string) => {
    return list.filter((obj) => {
       return obj["id"].includes(string);
    });
}

let isPresent = searchForString(list,"name");

console.log(isPresent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use indexOf without splitting in advance.

```js
function findItems(value) {
    value = value.toLowerCase();
    return list.filter(function (item) {
        return item.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1;
    });
}

var list = [{ id: "name1 Surname1", nb: 120 }, { id: "name2", nb: 632 }, { id: "name3Surname3", nb: 102 }, { id: "surname4", nb: 896 }];

console.log(findItems('name1'));
console.log(findItems('name1 Surn'));
console.log(findItems('name1 SurAAA'));
console.log(findItems('AAAA Surname1'));
console.log(findItems('ame1Surname1'));
console.log(findItems('name'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this gives me only results corresponding exactly to my list object value . this is not enough for me

Comment: No, it does not, it gives every object whose `id` contains the search string

Comment: I think, he want comma separated ids. Please add `.map(function(item){ return item.id }).join(',');` in `findItems` return statement.

Comment: @VipinKumar, i don't think so, because *"My result should be items whose IDS are containing my searched value item."*

Comment: correct @NinaScholz, I think question is not correct. Please see this too "*If I search for : "name" -> result : name1 Surname1 , name2 , name3Surname3 , surname4*"

Comment: @firasKoubaa, please add some example of search prases which does not work and add a wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

split the name string in to array and loop through the array and compare with the item id

```
function findItems(name){
    var l = list.filter(function(obj) {
        var ks = name.split(" ");

        for(var i = 0; i < ks.length ; i++){
            return obj.id.indexOf(ks[i]) >= 0
        }
    }); 
return l;
}
```